# Why does nested empty generator early exit without raising error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I am facing a strange behavior with nested [generators](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator).

```
def empty_generator():
    for i in []:
        yield

def gen():
    next(empty_generator())
    print("This is not printed, why?")
    yield

list(gen())  # No Error

next(empty_generator())  # Error
```

I would expect the `gen()` function to raises an error, as I am calling [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) around an empty generator. But this is not the case, the functions is leaving from nowhere, without raising or printing anything.

That seems to violate the principle of least astonishment, isn't it?

Comment: [This behavior is about to change.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you don't have an error; you have an uncaught `StopIteration` exception, which is used for flow control. The call to `list`, which takes an arbitrary iterable as its argument, catches the exception raised by `gen` for you.

`for` loops work similarly; every iterator raises `StopIteration` at the end, but the `for` loop catches it and ends in response.

Put another way, the consumer of an iterable is responsible for catching `StopIteration`. When `gen` calls `next`, it lets the exception bubble up. The call to `list` catches it, but you don't when you call `next` explicitly.

---

Note that [PEP-479](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/) changes this behavior. Python 3.5 provides the new semantics via `__future__`, Python 3.6 makes provides a deprecation warning, and Python 3.7 (due out Summer 2018) completes the transition. I refer the reader to the PEP itself for further details.

Comment: Replace `list(gen())` with `for x in gen(): pass`, still no error.

Comment: What a coincidence! I was submitting the bit about `for` loops just as your comment appeared :)

Comment: `StopIteration` as control flow of generators, that was the key to understand the behavior, thanks. Waiting for PEP479 impatiently. :)

Comment: You can use it today (with in 3.5 or later, anyway) with `from __future__ import generator_stop`.

Answer (score 1):

Once an iterator reaches its end, it raises `StopIteration` which... stops the iteration, so `list(gen())` constructs an empty list.